If there is no player on first base, will the runner on second still have to run to third base after a single?
I'm a baseball novice. My understanding is that when a batter runs all baserunners need to advance as well.
So, If there is no player on first base, will the runner on second still have to run to third base after a single?

No. Baserunners are "forced" off the base they occupy by preceding runners who are also "forced" to run. The batter must run to first. If there is anyone on first, they must run to second to make way for the batter, and so on. A player is typically forced to run to the next base if the base before them is occupied, but not if it's empty.
If a player is on second base with no one on first and the ball is hit, they do not have to run to third base. Even if the hitter rounds first and runs to second, the player on second is still not forced to run to third, because the player rounding first was not forced to run to second.

However, a player on 2nd usually will run if the batter decides to go for a double because if the batter hit it well enough to be a double, then there's almost always time to advance to third or home from 2nd.
